# How to retrieve a value of a public state variable from Solidity smart contract in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, ethereum, solidity, truffle, decentralized-applications

I am trying to return a value of a public state variable `highestBid` in solidity through JavaScript, what is a possible way to save the value from the call to a variable? Currently I am getting:
`undefined`.

TS:

```
    async getHighestBid() {
       this.smartAuction.setProvider(this.provider);
       let result = await this.smartAuction.deployed().
                         then(function(contract: { highestBid: { call: () => Promise<any>; }; })  {contract.highestBid.call().
                         then(function(v) {return v})});
       console.log(result);
  }
```

Sol:

```
contract SmartAuction {
    address payable public beneficiary;
    uint public auctionEnd;

    address public highestBidder;
    uint public highestBid;

    mapping(address => uint) private pendingReturns;

    bool private ended;
...
}
```

Comment: can you also chain catch to see the error?

Comment: @Yilmaz there seems to be no errors, the value is returned correctly while logging with console.log

Answer (score 1):

if `console.log(result)` logs correctly, you have to return `result` in the function so when you call the function, it will give you the `return` value.

```
 return result
```

in javascript if you do not return anything in a function, and if you call the function, it will execute the function body but it will return you `undefined`